# hide sign in form after 10s if cookie not set and no inputs are selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm developing a little function for my site where a sign in form is automatically shown in the navbar when the site is opened up, but only if a certain cookie has not been set. Then, after 10 seconds has passed, the form will disappear.

It is also supposed to stay open if the user has selected one of the form inputs **OR** if one of the inputs contain contents. (`#user-pest` or `#pass-pest`).

Most of it is working the way it is supposed to, however, even when one of the inputs is selected or contains contents, once 10 seconds has passed, the form will disappear from the page.

The following is the **JavaScript** (and **jQuery**) code that I am using (**updated**).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // hide sign in form

    function hideForm(){ // function for updating elements
        $("#darknet-login-nav").css("display", "none");
        $(".index-outer").css("height", "100px");
        $(".index-inner").css("width", "438px");
        $(".index-inner").css("top", "-10px");
        $("#darknet-mast").css("font-size", "97px");
    }

    function hideFormSet(){ // function used for updating elements and setting cookie
        hideForm();
        document.cookie = "signinNav=set";
    }

    var checkDisplayed = getCookie("signinNav"); // get cookie contents
    if(checkDisplayed == "set"){ 
        hideForm(); // if cookie is set, hide the form
    } else { // if it isn't
        var hideInterval = setInterval(hideFormSet, 10000); // after 10 seconds, call hideFormSet function
        if($("#user-pest").is(':focus') || $("#pass-pest").is(':focus')){
            clearInterval(hideInterval); // if one of the inputs are focused on, stop the interval
        } else {
            hideInterval; // if they aren't focused, start the interval
        }
    }
});
```

and this is my simplified markup.

```
<div class="darknet-nav-login-form" id="darknet-login-nav">
    <form action="" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="username" id="user-pest" placeholder="Username" autocomplete="off"><br>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="pass-pest" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="off"><br>
    </form>
</div>
```

I'm still very new to JavaScript, so any pointers and fixes will be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:** please check my above updated code.

Even when on of the inputs are focused, the interval will still continue, rather than stopping.

Thanks

Comment: Ways to improve maintainability, you should convert the 5 css-method calls to a function that you call so that you don't have to duplicate the same code.

Comment: @Esko how would I do that?

Comment: `function myFunction() { $("#darknet-login-nav").css("display", "none");
                $(".index-outer").css("height", "100px"); }` and then myFunction(); when you want to call it

Comment: `setInterval` does two things. (0) It starts a timer and (1) it returns an identifier for that timer. Using this identifier, one may cancel the timer with a call to `clearInterval`.

Comment: Haha, how would I do that? xD still very new to JS @enhzflep

Comment: `var timerId = setInterval(function,milliseconds,param1,param2,...);` then, later when/if needed, `clearInterval(timerId);` See more here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

Comment: @enhzflep please check the new update :)

Comment: This makes no sense. --> `hideInterval; // if they aren't focused, start the interval`. It's no different really to writing `100; // if they aren't focused`...

Comment: @enhzflep what do you mean? how would I do it then... :-/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your goal correctly, you also want to hide the form 10 seconds after the inputs lose focus. 
In that case it's easier to bind to the focusin/focusout events to restart the timeout, otherwise when leaving an input just before the interval fires it is hidden much earlier than the timeout.

```
var inputs = $('#user-pest, #pass-pest'),
    hideTimeout,
    checkFocus = function(){
        var hide = !inputs.is(':focus');
        if(hide===!!hideTimeout)return;
        if(hide)
            hideTimeout = setTimeout(hideFormSet, 10000);
        else
            hideTimeout = clearTimeout(hideTimeout);
        };

inputs.focusin(checkFocus).focusout(checkFocus);
checkFocus();
```

Sidenote, jQuery's `is` method checks if any of the elements in the jq array corresponds to the selector, so instead of a separate and/or, you can do: `$('#user-pest, #pass-pest').is(':focus')`

[example Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wkkhy4zv/)

Sidenote2, the (re)binding will occur twice because one input loses focus before the next one gains focus. This is not a problem in itself, but if the form only contains those 2 inputs, using event bubbling to check focus on the form itself might be one little step further optimized: `inputs.parent().focusin(checkFocus).focusout(checkFocus);`

Comment: is there supposed to be two `!` here: `hide===!!hideTimeout`?

Comment: Thnakyou! Works perfectly :-)

Comment: Yep, the `!!` is intentional to truthify hideTimeout. It forces hideTimeout to be a boolean value. e.g. `!!undefined === false` , so is `!!0` where as `!!anynumber === true` (and glad it helped :) )

Comment: ohhh, smart! Haha, I never knew that :) thanks for the little tutorial

Answer (score 3):

You need an && in this line.

```
if(!$("#user-pest").is(':focus') || !$("#pass-pest").is(':focus')){
```

What you had before was

```
if( user-pest is not focused OR pass-pest is not focused)
```

A user can't focus both of them at once, thus this will always evaluate to true and hide will be set to true. Use the following:

```
if(!$("#user-pest").is(':focus') && !$("#pass-pest").is(':focus')){
```

Alternatively you could also use the following

```
if($("#user-pest").is(':focus') || $("#pass-pest").is(':focus')){
    var hide = false;
} else {
    var hide = true;
}
```

As pointed out in your comment there is also another problem, which I missed the first time.

The hide variable is set on page load, which happens instantly, and you most likely won't have had the time to focus either object yet. You should move the code that checks if it's focused to inside the timeout callback.

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/28r917oL/3/) for the full code of a working example. Basically your timeout should check if the inputs are focused when run, not on page load, as seen in the following snippet.

```
setTimeout(function() {
  if (!$("#user-pest").is(':focus') && !$("#pass-pest").is(':focus')) {
    $("#darknet-login-nav").css("display", "none");
    $(".index-outer").css("height", "100px");
    $(".index-inner").css("width", "438px");
    $(".index-inner").css("top", "-10px");
    $("#darknet-mast").css("font-size", "97px");
    document.cookie = "signinNav=set"; // set the cookie so the form doesn't appear when they come back later
  }
}, 2000);
```

Comment: Hmm.. Won't this will do the same thing? Because if neither of them are selected at the same time, it will always hide it. But, I get what you mean

Comment: Ahh, just saw the edit. I understand now :) will check to see if it works. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, it still hides, even if it is selected.. Anything else you can see?

Comment: @CaelanGrgurovic Ah, yes, updated my answer with another problem.

Comment: it kind of works now :-), however, if the input is selected and then the user clicks off, it won't trigger a 10s timeout anymore and disappear... :/

Comment: any ideas on how to do?

Comment: @CaelanGrgurovic You could use an interval to check, and clear the interval when the inputs are hidden. See http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp for some simple examples.

Comment: Potentially you could also bind to focusout event for your input fields, and start the timout then. https://api.jquery.com/focusout/

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution which ensures that the inputs are each empty and that they're not focused. Behaviour beyond the initial 10s timeout wasn't specified, so I've left the interval active - the hide behaviour will be invoked any time the timeout elapses and the conditions for hiding the header are met.

If you wish to make it a 'one-shot' timer, simply `clearInterval` in the `intervalHandler` function.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', onDocLoaded, false);

var intervalHandle;

function onDocLoaded(evt)
{
 intervalHandle = setInterval(intervalHandler, 2000);
}

function hideHeader()
{
 document.getElementById('darknet-login-nav').classList.add('hidden');
}

// returns true/false
// true if the header should be hidden, false otherwise.
// Things that will prevent the header from being hidden area
// 0) content in the #user-pest input
// 1) content in the #pass-pest input
// 2) focus of either #user-pest or #pass-pest elements
function shouldHideHeader()
{
 if (document.getElementById('user-pest').value != '')
  return false;
  
 if (document.getElementById('pass-pest').value != '')
  return false;
  
 if (document.activeElement == document.getElementById('user-pest'))
  return false;
  
 if (document.activeElement == document.getElementById('pass-pest'))
  return false;
  
 return true;
}


function intervalHandler()
{
 if (shouldHideHeader())
  hideHeader();
}
```

```css
.darknet-nav-login-form
{
 height: 42px;
}
.hidden
{
 height: 0px;
 overflow: hidden;
 transition: height 2s;
}
```

```html
<div class="darknet-nav-login-form" id="darknet-login-nav">
  <form action="" method="post">
   <input type="text" name="username" id="user-pest" placeholder="Username" autocomplete="off"/><br>
   <input type="password" name="password" id="pass-pest" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="off"/><br>
  </form>
 </div>
```